# What improvements are needed in jira

Tags: jira

As most IT companies use jira these days. Since it is a huge and complex application. But still it needs some improvements. Can someone share what improvements are needed for jira or any problem you faced while using jira?

I am asking this because in my last interview I was asked about this question, which I didnt expect, since I havent used jira so I don't know much about it. I need your help so I will be prepared in future interviews.

Comment: @podiluska I mean many or several.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atlassian tracks what users vote on at their own public JIRA instance. Here's a [link](https://jira.atlassian.com/secure/IssueNavigator.jspa?reset=true&jqlQuery=project%20=%20JRA%20and%20status%20=%20Open%20order%20by%20votes) to all their open JIRA issues sorted by the number of votes. Alternatively, you can read the JIRAAAARGH! chapter in my book [Practical JIRA Administration](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920020196.do).

~Matt

Answer (score 1):

The list is long, and depends on what you are planning to use Jira for, such as:

- who use it? (customers, developers, support, sales)
- do you need  svn/git support?
- planning to use agile?
- how do you want to open issues?

As well, while you might find many things missing, the big benefit of using Jira is that you can write your own code to achieve nearly everything.

To our needs, we found the following missing:

- ability to rank issues
- sending email for non Jira users
- saving mail templates
- 24hrs issue notification
- agile support (need to buy greenhoper to really support it)
- front-end web forms for issue creation

You can also check [Jira's new features requests](https://jira.atlassian.com/secure/IssueNavigator.jspa?reset=true&jqlQuery=project%20=%20JRA%20AND%20resolution%20=%20Unresolved%20AND%20issuetype%20=%20%22New%20Feature%22%20ORDER%20BY%20priority%20DESC&mode=hide)  and [improvments](https://jira.atlassian.com/secure/IssueNavigator.jspa?reset=true&jqlQuery=project%20=%20JRA%20AND%20resolution%20=%20Unresolved%20AND%20issuetype%20=%20Improvement%20ORDER%20BY%20priority%20DESC&mode=hide)

Comment: My question is for developers. As a developer what things need to be improved.

Comment: I am a developer. This is the things that were missing in Jira for our development team.

Comment: About second point. Why would you need to send emails to non jira users?

Comment: We use Jira as our support system. When people send email to Jira, issues are being created for us, developers. Once we fix a bug (or nor), we want to send an email, preferably from a template, telling the users that the issue was fixed (or not). As well, the support team have asked us to implements some sort of "Frequently asked questions" db, so they could send solution directly from Jira.